# How do I send image to the server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an image to the server using retrofit, multipart/form-data. But I get an error.

I've tried send an image by Postman, it was ok.

```
@Multipart
@POST("requests/11006/history")
fun sendMessageWithImg(
    @Header("X-Device-UDID") deviceUDID: String = "",
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
): Call<ResponseBody>


private fun upload(fileUri: Uri) {
    val tokenStorage = TokenStorage(this)
    val token = tokenStorage.getToken()
    val originalFile = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri)

    val filePart = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse(contentResolver.getType(fileUri)),
        originalFile)

    val file: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image[]", originalFile.name, filePart)

    val client = ApiService.create()

    val call: Call<ResponseBody> = client
        .sendMessageWithImg(
            token = "Bearer $token",
            image = file)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody>{

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            print(call)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            print(response)
        }

    })
}
```

Error is - failed to connect to *.30::681c:587 (port 443) from /fec0::9c04.* (port 38630) after 10000ms

Comment: Is it only the image upload that's failing? could you reach your server from your mobile app to do other stuff?

Comment: you are getting error on only this web service(Api) or in all api's

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/updateprofile")
Observable<ResponseBody> updateProfile(@Part("user_id") RequestBody id,
                                   @Part("full_name") RequestBody fullName,
                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                   @Part("other") RequestBody other);



 //pass it like this
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Corrections 6.jpg");
RequestBody requestFile =
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body =
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

// add another part within the multipart request
 RequestBody fullName = 
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "Your Name");

  service.updateProfile(id, fullName, body, other);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what might be happening:

1- Your phone cannot reach the server because it's not connected to the internet or the same network as your server. Make sure the connection in working.

2- The phone can reach the server, but the image is so big that it takes more than the default timeout of 10 seconds used in your Http client. If you are using OkHttp as the Http client for Retrofit, then you can change this timeout values for some higher value ([Check this link for more info)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-customize-network-timeouts):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

3- The problem can also be on the server-side. If the Image Size limit that's set on the server is lower than the actual size of the image, that could be the reason it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //add perimissiom in mainfests
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    //interface    
        @Multipart
        @POST("requests/11006/history")
        fun sendMessageWithImg(
                           @Part("X-Device-UDID") RequestBody deviceUDID,
                            @Part("Authorization") RequestBody token,
           @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file1
        ): Call<ResponseBody>

     //below code placed in your Activity java class inside of oncreate
    chooseanimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        // intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        Log.i("cameraa", "01");
                    }
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select"), 0);
                }
            });

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                //Do not need to check the permission
            } else {
                RequestMultiplePermission();
            }



      upload..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadalbum(fileUris);
});



           //below code placed in your Activity java class outside of oncreate
                  private void RequestMultiplePermission() {

                    // Creating String Array with Permissions.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Create_Project.this, new String[]
                            {
                                    CAMERA,
                                    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                            }, RequestPermissionCode);
                }
                 @NonNull
                    private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
                        return RequestBody.create(
                                okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
                        // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
                        // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
                        //   File file = new File(strImgaepath);
                        File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);
                        // create RequestBody instance from file
                        RequestBody requestFile =
                                RequestBody.create(
                                        MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                                        file
                                );

                        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
                    }


       @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == 0 && data != null) {


                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                    int currentItem = 0;
                    while (currentItem < count) {
                        Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();
                        //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
                        currentItem = currentItem + 1;
                        Log.d("Uri Selected", imageUri.toString());
                        try {
                            // Get the file path from the URI
                            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, imageUri);
                            Log.d("Multiple File Selected", path);

                            fileUris.add(imageUri);
                            //  MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Create_Project.this, arrayList);
                            // listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //   Log.e(TAG, "File select error", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                    //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.i("sara", "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        // Get the file path from the URI
                        final String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
                        Log.d("Single File Selected", path);

                        fileUris.add(uri);

                        if (fileUris != null) {
                            setimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("sara", "File select error", e);
                    }
                }
            }





        }


    //upolad image
     private void uploadalbum(ArrayList<Uri> fileUris) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            ApiGetPost service = ApiConstant.getMainUrl(getApplicationContext()).create(ApiGetPost.class);


            List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileUris.size(); i++) {

                parts.add(prepareFilePart("file_upload[]", fileUris.get(i)));
                Log.i("sara", String.valueOf(fileUris.get(i)));
            }


            updateMyProfile = service.upload(createPartFromString(strtitle),

                    createPartFromString(""),
                    createPartFromString(""), parts);

            updateMyProfile.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ModelLogin> call, Response<ModelLogin> response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    ModelLogin user = response.body();
                    String sa = String.valueOf(user.getStatus());
                    String msg = user.getMessage();

                    if (sa.equals("true")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ModelLogin> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
```